# How to link ffmpeg statically using mingw?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, static, g++

My application compiles success, but when run it can not find avcodec-57.dll, avdevice-57.dll and other ffmpeg libraries. I need a static app with no dependencies. Here is compiler's log:

```
cd 'D:\Projects\Test1'
D:\Programms\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Release
"/D/Programms/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/Projects/Test1'
"/D/Programms/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/test1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/Projects/Test1'
mkdir -p build/Release/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++ -m32 -static -mwindows   -c -O2 -I/D/Programms/MinGW/ffmpeg/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Release/MinGW-Windows
g++ -m32 -static -mwindows    -o dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/test1 build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/Programms/MinGW/ffmpeg/lib -lavdevice.dll -lavformat.dll -lavutil.dll
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Projects/Test1'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Projects/Test1'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (time: 3s)
```

(IDE: NetBeans; Compiler: MinGW)

Maybe I missed something?

Comment: `g++ -m32 -static -mwindows    -o dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/test1 build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/Programms/MinGW/ffmpeg/lib -lavdevice -lavformat -lavutil` you need the libs and not the dlls

Also those libs must be build statically, otherwise they will try to load a dll. You can download the static version [here (https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Comment: I downloaded a dev version from this page. There is no libs or headers in Static version, just exe for console. Maybe I need to add some parameters to compiler or linker to connect libs staticaly?

Comment: WOW! I just found string "--disable-static" in README file... Think I need to build ffmpeg...

Comment: Yes in this case you need to build ffmpeg

Comment: Damn... There are lot of other libraries to build ffmpeg, and the manual describes only how to build exe. But I need dev tools with possibility of static builds. Maybe somebody has such dev tools?