# How statically link ffmpeg with cgo correctly

Tags: cgo

I am making a ffmpeg program with cgo. I wanna statically link ffmpeg into the program.

I write these in cgo

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall -I./include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/lib -llibavformat  -llibavcodec -llibavutil -llibavdevice -llibavfilter -llibswresample -llibswscale

#include "ffmpeg.h"
*/
import "C"
```

It builds successfully. But it will report "mssing avxxx.dll" while running. I guess it is compiled via dynamic linking.

Comment: I am curious what the solution was? if you have an example repo and code snippet that would be awesome!

Comment: The only way is building the ffmpeg libraries by yourself. @JoeWilliams

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first comment on this prior question has your answer: [How to link ffmpeg statically using mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41464125/1987437)

Essentially, you have to have the static version of libffmpeg and `-static` in the CFLAGS. The bad news is that is looks like libffmpeg does not ship with static libraries so you may have to build it yourself (read the lower comments in that answer).

Comment: Hi, Liam Kelly. Thank you for your reply. I have notice that ffmpeg doesn't offer the static libraries. I am trying to compile it myself now. I do it successfully but it is unexpected. It dosen't support many format such as mov, mp4... even if I compile it with `--enable-muxers`, `--enable-demuxers`. Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: @ryoii i just looked at the `configure` and I just see [--enable-muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Muxers)  (no `s`) you might have to individually list which ones you want.